# Generating Cs file from xsd

Tags: c#

I am trying to generate a Cs [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) file from an XSD I have. I have tried executing the following command:

```
D:\>xsd /dataset /language:CS /outputdir:D:\UKBTrunk\SaaS UKB Core Trunk\Shared\d
otNet\BT.SaaS.Core.Shared\BT.SaaS.Core.Shared.Interfaces\SharedContracts\CMPS\Re
sponse getAgreementPlanChangeHistory.xsd
```

I am getting the error:

> *Error: invalid command line argument: 'UKB'.*

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message gave it away; the program considers `UKB` not to be a part of the path.

Add quotes:

```
D:\>xsd /dataset /language:CS/outputdir:"D:\UKBTrunk\SaaS UKB Core Trunk\Shared\dotNet\BT.SaaS.Core.Shared\BT.SaaS.Core.Shared.Interfaces\SharedContracts\CMPS\Response" getAgreementPlanChangeHistory.xsd
```